# How To Redirect Whole site to another site except the Root Page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, web

I want to redirect every url of my site except the root i.e., the home `index.html`

Basically I want everything after the / to redirect.

For example: If I visit `website.com` it should normally show the index.html page placed in the root. But if I goto `website.com/someurl` then it should redirect to `website2.com/someurl`

The site shouldn't redirect only for the root (home) page, and Should redirect for all other links.

Another 2 things I might add is:

1. The `website2.com` is https connection
2. I also want to use it in sub domain. i.e., at `sub.website.com`

Please help me with the relevant `.htaccess` code.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code finally worked for me:

> RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteBase /
>
> RewriteRule ^.+$ https://newsite.com/$0 [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and check

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.website.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website2.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.website\.com$ [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.website2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hello. It isnt working. 2 important things I might add, 1: the website2.com is a https connection. and I also want to use it in subdomains i.e., at sub.website.com.. Currently I'm trying out the code in subdomain.

Comment: @CodyCodes are you expecting like this

http://sub.website.com/$1 to https://sub.website2.com/$1  ?

Comment: Yes. And the root i.e., sub.website.com is not working with the above code.